# What do you call the product of a circle and an annulus?

Tags: terminology, gn.general-topology, 3-manifolds

What would you call the product of an annulus and $S^1$ (a 'thickened' torus like 3-manifold)?

More generally, is there an archive or list online of names assigned to various (non-standard) manifolds by people? Or a set convention by which to name them?

Comment: A tubular neighborhood of the torus.

Comment: @Steve That only makes sense if it's embedded in an ambient polyhedron.

Comment: Sorry to reretag, but "names" is more apt that "notation".

Comment: A common way to name manifolds is via cobordism + surgery.  Thom classified manifolds up to cobordism, and you get between any two cobordant manifolds via surgery.  So that's a common (if highly ambiguous) naming convention.  Moskovich's response falls under the verbiage of fibre bundle terminology, which is far less ambiguous. 

Comment: I also added the tag "3-manifolds".

Comment: at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:3-manifolds you could see some propose. Would be a place to start proposal. Personaly I like "moxi" for $M\ddot{o}\times I$ and twisted-moxi to $M\ddot{o}^\stackrel{\sim}\times I$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call it a thickened torus. I don't know how standard that is, but it is quite normal to speak of thickened manifolds, where one means that manifold times a closed interval.
I have long felt that there should be a mathematical dictionary- not an encyclopaedia, by a dictionary- in order to fix and record standard usage.

Comment: A trivial $I$-bundle over a torus would be another -- since there are non-orientable $I$-bundles over the torus this is a tiny bit more specific. 

Comment: @Ryan: $M\ddot{o}\times S^1$ is the non-orientable twisted $I$-bundle over the torus.

Answer (score 1):

that corresponds to the complement of a trivial (but essencial) torus knot in a open solid torus. For those -Fico had mention- they are called cable spaces and have nice foliation into circles. Its name is **CS(1,0)**. Can you see what is CS(2,1)?

Edit at: utc-6 = 11:50 approx

you could also say **the trivial I-bundle over the torus**

Answer (score 0):

May I {humbly} suggest "inner tube", as in "Floating down the river in an ... " ?
(Strike while the terminological iron is hot.)

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.02.09